# Configuring tesseract for XCODE project(IPHONE)

Tags: iphone, xcode, tesseract

I have downloaded tesseract, configured it and got some .a files too. But after adding the framework files and running my XCODE project, it is giving plenty of errors from the framework libraries ???!!

Can anyone please explain in detail about the steps of installation and configuration of tesseract to work with xcode?

Comment: important!!! i am able to run the tesseract from terminal and it is working perfectly with me.. I just want the details of configuration and steps to work in xcode.

Comment: What is tesseract? What errors are you getting?

Comment: tesseract is an OCR engine. problem is about the configuration of tesseract with iphone project.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [project](https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR).

Make sure you have added the header search path and library search path in the project settings as shown in the sample application.